# Deploying another version of approval process - what happens to the pending records?

Tags: approval-process, approval-step

I have an active approval process in production - named qualification approval 1.
and now added a new step to the new version of the approval process named qualification approval 2.

The idea was to deploy the qualification approval 2 and deactivate qualification approval 1 as post-deployment.

But there are several records pending in production. What would happen to those records? What can I do to ensure I move these records to the new version?

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What would happen to those records?

Nothing. They remain the the approval process as they were.

> What can I do to ensure I move these records to the new version?

You should reject/approve/delete any pending requests, then submit them for approval again.

Comment: Thank you @sfdcfox.